# User feed returns only single most recent post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-rest-api

I had my code work fine yesterday, but today I can no longer get the feed from the user that authorized my app.

When calling `https://graph.facebook.com/userID/feed?access_token=XXX` in the app or browser I get only one item in the feed - the most recent wall post. Following `previous` and `next` links yields empty `data` array.

User has about 160 wall posts that I was able to fetch yesterday with the same code. I think the more worrying thing is that I can't even get those posts in the browser.

The access token is valid. Application authorized.

Does anybody have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this: https://graph.facebook.com/userID/feed?access_token=XXX&limit=500

Comment: Okay, that sort of worked... It gave me 11 items out of 160 and next/previous links still give an empty array. Am I not getting the proper meaning of `limit`? Isn't it the limit on returned posts? How will I paginate with just the limit (if it worked)?

Comment: Yup, definitely not the right solution. I wonder if Facebook changed something or I'm missing something.

Comment: Apparently, the `access_token` I was getting from FB was not correct. It wasn't rejected but returned weird results.

Then I switched to using `offline_access` permission and it works fine now.